# xcode pods : unknown type name 'link' : link to non existing header file?

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, cocoapods, header-files

As a C#  Developer who inherited an iOS app,
I'm struggling to build/run this app.
Xcode throws errors for a header file, which (I think ) it cannot find.

When i open the file
(Pods/Headers/Build/CocoaSecurity/CocoaSecurity.h)
, it shows as its contents:

link ../../../CocoaSecurity/CocoaSecurity/CocoaSecurity.h

the file's location is 
(Pods/CocoaSecurity/CocoaSecurity/CocoaSecurity.h)

Error message:

```
unknown type name link
```

[image: please see screenshot]

Thanks for helping out guys, the thing is, wouldn't pod install just get the file contents? 
The file the link seems to point to already exists ?
[screenshot with file location/contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaMHo.png)

Comment: have you performed a pod install yet?

Comment: thanks, i already did. diddly squat. see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably re-install all components that were added using the Cocoa-Pods mechanism.

Create a text file "fixPods.sh" with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My example bash script
echo "-------- Renaming original Podfile..."
mv podfile podfile.temp
echo "-------- Creating empty Podfile..."
pod init
echo "-------- Removing all pods..."
pod install
echo "-------- Deleting empty Podfile..."
rm podfile
echo "-------- Restoring original Podfile..."
mv podfile.temp podfile
echo "-------- Restoring all pods"
pod install
```

Open terminal and navigate to the project folder (cd [folder path]). You can drag the folder icon into the terminal screen to get the path.
To run the script, type:

```
./fixPods.sh
```

Comment: sorry, didn't help.
ran pod install, as well as this script.